Generate only strings or integers as Map values with Instancio
I have an object MyObject which has several nested fields. Some of them are of type Map<String, Object>.
Without further configuration, Instancio generates plain Object instances as values for the map. Instead, I would like Instancio to generate only a String or Integer as value.
My current solution is to create a custom generator, but this is very limited.
public class CustomMapGenerator implements Generator<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> generate(Random random) {
        return Map.of(random.lowerCaseAlphabetic(5), random.lowerCaseAlphabetic(5));
    }

    @Override
    public Hints hints() {
        return Generator.super.hints();
    }
}


There are a couple of options that I think should work.
The first option is to map Select.all(Object.class) to a custom generator. In the example below, a map instance may contain both, String and Integer values at the same. If you prefer not to mix types, it should be pretty straightforward to restrict each map to either strings or integers only:
class StringOrIntergerGenerator implements Generator<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object generate(final Random random) {
        return random.trueOrFalse()
                ? random.lowerCaseAlphabetic(5)
                : Integer.valueOf(random.intRange(0, 1000));
    }
}

@Test
void example() {
    MyObject myObject = Instancio.of(MyObject.class)
            .supply(Select.all(Object.class), new StringOrIntergerGenerator())
            .create();

    // snip...
}

The downside of the above approach is that you would have to always map Object to a custom generator manually.
The second option is to define a custom GeneratorProvider SPI. With this approach, you can have the generator resolved automatically. You can find a sample project with an example here:
https://github.com/instancio/instancio-samples/tree/main/generator-provider-sample
